# BASH Loop how to go about it?

Tags: bash, shell

Ok I have a tower of 8 HDD's and I'm trying to make a script that will loop through them and make a text file with the results (info from hdparm) for each HDD in there own folders. How can I now loop this script to go for sdc -> /Bay2, sdd -> /Bay3, sde -> /Bay4 ect ect

This is working now for one HDD just need to loop it for the other 7

```
if [ -c /dev/sdb ];
then
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb >> /Bay1/sdb.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This relies on glob matching `/dev/sdX` and the command `seq` to generate the 1..8:

```
hd=( dummy /dev/sd[b-z] )

for i in `seq 1 8`
do
    sudo hdparm -I ${hd[$i]} >> /Bay$i/`basename ${hd[$i]}`.txt
done
```

The `dummy` entry in the `hd` array just makes it one-based.

You could restructure it to operate on `/dev/sd[b-z]` (letting it match any number, not expecting 8) and counting as in @sampson-chen's answer with `for sd in /dev/sd[b-z] ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
    # start with lower case b, so ascii starts at 98 instead of 65
    ascii=66 
    index=1
    total=8
    while [[ $total -ge $index ]]
    do
        letter=$(echo "$ascii" | awk '{ printf("%c",$0); }')
        if [ -c /dev/sd$letter ];
        then
            sudo hdparm -I /dev/sd$letter >> /Bay$index/sd$letter.txt
        fi
        index=$((index+1))
        ascii=$((ascii+1))
    done
```

Edit: fixed total / index misplacement and offset (98) for lower case letters

Just tested this with `touch` to create the files on Linux and it works.

Comment: @BenJackson Good catch! Tough habit to fix.

Comment: Shouldn't the `if`-statement be inside the `while`-loop, and based on `/dev/sd$letter` instead of `/dev/sdb`?